# Using LibXML and XPath To Find Node With Colon (Local Namespace)

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, libxml2

I'm trying to get the attribute `@id1` from `<Incoming>` in the below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Incomings xmlns:ns2="http://testme.org/foo/schema">
    <Incoming id1="6bbaec22" id2="928c2081">
        <ns2:Address>fubar@test.com</ns2:Address>
    </Incoming>
</Incomings>
```

The only information that I can pass in is the email address `fubar@test.com`

I'm using `XML::LibXML` and `XML::LibbXML::XPathContext` as below:

```
my $dom = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file( $xml_file );  # XML contains as above
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $dom->documentElement );
$xpc->registerNs('x', 'http://testme.org/foo/schema');

my $email = 'fubar@test.com';
my $xpath = "/x:Incomings/x:Incoming/x:ns2:Address[text()='$email']/../\@id1";
my @nodes = $xpc->findnodes( $xpath );
```

But it always gives me an invalid expression in `$xpath` around the *ns2:Address*.

What mistake did I make above? If the node name is only `<Address>` then removing the *ns2:* from my `$xpath` statement giving me the correct values in `@nodes`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's two problems here - first off, `xpath` expressions find nodes. You can search based on the existence and content of an attribute, but `findnodes` will give you the element, not the content.

Secondly - you can't nest namespaces in XML. `x:ns2:Address` isn't valid. Do you actually need to register your `x` namespace there? You may not need to at all. (e.g. based on your small XML snippet).

Can I offer an alternative option? Because you're working with `perl` you don't actually necessarily need to do everything via the xpath expression.

I'd be perhaps thinking `findnodes` followed by `grep`:

NB: Using XML::Twig for illustration - pretty sure something pretty similar works in XML::LibXML.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' )->parse( \*DATA );

my @elt_list = grep { $_->trimmed_text =~ m{fubar\@test.com} }
    ( $twig->findnodes('//ns2:Address') );

foreach my $elt (@elt_list) {
    print $elt -> parent -> att('id1');
}


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Incomings xmlns:ns2="http://testme.org/foo/schema">
    <Incoming id1="6bbaec22" id2="928c2081">
        <ns2:Address>fubar@test.com</ns2:Address>
    </Incoming>     
</Incomings>
```

I'd also note - your xpath lets you find an element - rather than an attribute - so you can select on 'elements with an `id1` attribute like this:

```
my @elt_list = ( $twig->findnodes("//ns2:Address[string()='$email']/../.[\@id1]") );

foreach my $elt (@elt_list) {
    print $elt -> att('id1');
}
```

Depends rather on how specific you want to be with your `findnodes` search. Based on what you've provided in that snippet, you've gone for much too complicated, and could simply do:

```
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->parsefile('your_file.xml'); 
print $twig -> findnodes('//Incoming',0)->att('id1'),"\n";
```

Or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file( 'sample2.xml' );
foreach my $node (  $xml -> findnodes( '//Incoming' ) ) {
   print $node ->getAttribute('id1'), "\n";
}
```

Or with a bit of grepping:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $email = 'fubar@test.com';
my $xml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file( 'sample2.xml' );
foreach my $node ( grep { $_ -> textContent =~ m{$email} } $xml -> findnodes( '//Incoming' ) ) {
   print $node ->getAttribute('id1'), "\n";
}
```

If you particularly want to be using that `x` namespace though - this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml   = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('sample2.xml');
my $xpc   = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $xml->documentElement );
$xpc->registerNs( 'x', 'http://testme.org/foo/schema' );

my $email = 'fubar@test.com';
my ( $id1 ) = map { $_ -> getAttribute('id1') // () } $xpc->findnodes("/Incomings/Incoming/x:Address[text()='$email']/..");
print $id1,"\n";
```

(Also works if I mock up some XML with multiple 'Incoming' nodes to select the first with the right email address. Note `//` is perl 5.10 onwards, and is a conditional on 'defined'. You could probably substitute it with `||` on older versions, which is 'true/false' - the only places where there's differences is empty strings and zeros)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answers and showing alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Try the path `"/Incomings/Incoming[x:Address = '$email']/@id1"`. If the Perl string literal needs the escape `\@id1`, then keep that in, i.e. `"/Incomings/Incoming[x:Address = '$email']/\@id1"`.

Answer (score 1):

In two instances, you're searching for the element in the wrong namespaces, and in one instance. you're using two prefixes which makes no sense. Fixed:

```
my $email = 'fubar@test.com';
my $xpath = "/Incomings/Incoming/x:Address[text()='$email']/../\@id1";
my @nodes = $xpc->findnodes($xpath);
```

I prefer to avoid using `..`. I'd use the following:

```
my $email = 'fubar@test.com';
my $xpath = "/Incomings/Incoming[x:Address/text()='$email']/\@id1";
my @nodes = $xpc->findnodes($xpath);
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami  - if I could accept two solutions I would've done so as your answer here solves my original problem.